# Should "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" throw an error if it fails to update a UNIQUE KEY?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm having an issue where when I use "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" with a UNIQUE field there is a silent failure.  Here is the scenerio:

1) I have a mapping table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE index_user_username (
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (username, id)
);
```

notice `username` is marked as `UNIQUE`

2) I insert a few entries:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO index_user_username (username,id) VALUES ('dude', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username=VALUES(username);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO index_user_username (username,id) VALUES ('man', 2) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username=VALUES(username);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

here is my sanity check on the db:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM index_user_username;
+----------+----+
| username | id |
+----------+----+
| dude     |  1 |
| man      |  2 |
+----------+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

3) I update one of the rows as one of the other's username but i dont get a failure (I get "`Query OK`"):

```
mysql> INSERT INTO index_user_username (username,id) VALUES ('dude', 2) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username=VALUES(username);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM index_user_username;
+----------+----+
| username | id |
+----------+----+
| dude     |  1 |
| man      |  2 |
+----------+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So my main question is, shouldn't this throw an error?  And if not, any suggestions on options for work arounds (also, see note below)?  Also, I'm running version 5.6.13

**Clarification**:
the "id" field maps to another table.  this is a unique username-to-userId mapping table, essentially.

---

**as a side note:** I did notice that in the command-line I get a response telling me how many rows are affected and thought that I could do some checking and throw an error in my code if 0 affected rows comes up.  However, I implemented this all using the node.js module (https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) and it seems to return the same response for all of the above INSERT statements:

```
{ fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 1,
    insertId: 0,
    serverStatus: 2,
    warningCount: 0,
    message: '',
    protocol41: true,
    changedRows: 0 }
```

Any help figuring out why this seems to be giving me the wrong feedback would be helpful as well.

Comment: Can you please explain in plain words what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like an update/insert operation that does all of the following (assume the operation is on index_user_username table above): 1) if the "id" and "username" don't exist in the table, a new row is inserted 2) if the id exists but username doesnt the username is updated on the row that contains the "id" 3) if both the username and id exist in the table the operation fails.  The INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE operation I have above does all of these things, but case 3 fails without an error. In my code I can't tell there is a failure. I need to know it fails so i can handle that case.

Comment: one other case i didnt mention above: 4) username exists but the id doesnt, the insert should fail.  that is working fine in my INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement (it is throwing an error unlike case 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some investigation, I think i found my answer.  From the mysql docs on "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax"

> In general, you should try to avoid using an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>   clause on tables with multiple unique indexes.

(I assume it is partially because of the ambiguity in multiple matches on UNIQUEs like in my case)

Also, from the node.js side of things, I believe I found a work-around that allows me to figure out what happened after the update and respond accordingly.  I found some issues/pulls that describe similar problems I was having, for example:

- https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/pull/237

which pointed me to blacklisting FOUND_ROWS:

- https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#connection-flags

So, given:

```
CREATE TABLE index_user_username (
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (username, id)
);
```

if I have the following script:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection('mysql://root:rootpass@localhost/user?flags=-FOUND_ROWS');
connection.connect()
connection.query('INSERT INTO index_user_username (username,id) VALUES (\'dude\', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username=VALUES(username)', function(err,result) {
  console.log('1:',result.affectedRows)
  connection.query('INSERT INTO index_user_username (username,id) VALUES (\'man\', 2) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username=VALUES(username)', function(err,result) {
    console.log('2:',result.affectedRows)
    connection.query('INSERT INTO index_user_username (username,id) VALUES (\'dude\', 2) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username=VALUES(username)', function(err,result) {
      console.log('3:',result.affectedRows)
      connection.query('INSERT INTO index_user_username (username,id) VALUES (\'dude\', 3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username=VALUES(username)', function(err,result) {
        console.log('4:',result.affectedRows)
        connection.end()
      })
    })
  })
})
```

I get the output:

```
1: 1
2: 1
3: 0
4: 0
```

which is what I need, where previously I was getting:

```
1: 1
2: 1
3: 1
4: 1
```

Which didnt give me feeback about what just happened.

Answer (score 1):

The ON DUPLICATE KEY clause has no *need* to update the unique key. It's already there. Just remove that column from the update.

Answer (score 0):

But it did update with the same name.Unique key only prevents two identical values and not an update with the same value.Dont you mean

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id)
```

Comment: To be clear "id" maps to the "id" field in another table (user id in this case).  Also, I want to make sure that I keep a single username-to-id mapping.  i think the above would be wrong because it would change the user associated with the username.  In other words, you would steal a username from another user.

Comment: Yes,but that has nothing to do with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.Use ON UPDATE CASCADE on that foreign key.